# Duplicate Administrator Accounts

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, security

Somehow, I have a Windows 2003 Server that has two local Administrator accounts that have the same SID (S-21-xxxxxxxxx-500).    Therefore, normal utilities don't let me delete them.  (Can't delete a builtin account).  I've tried removing them through the following means without any luck:

net user /delete
compmgmt.msc
wmic username rename/delete
GPO to rename the administrator
password recovery boot disks

I've run out of ideas.  Anyone have any insight?

I'm not sure how the duplication occured but it probably has something to do with the fact that we had a GPO in place that renames the Administrator account.  I'd guess that GPO was applying and something crashed.  It left both accounts.

Comment: is this a new server?

Comment: it's a test server that's been in 'production' for a few years

Comment: does it have a backup sam file?  If I remember correctly w2k3 will do an initial backup of the sam the only thing then is you'll need to crack the pw.

Comment: all the backups we have of the server contain both administrator accounts.

Still no luck with this.  Running out of options.  It's not causing issues per se, but it could down the road.  May just need to rebuild the server.

Answer (score 0):

try using Windows NT offline password and registry editor

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

you should be able to boot from it and remove the Duplicate account